# Delphi & Indy & utf8

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe6

i have a problem to access into websites whit utf8 charset, for example when i try to accesso at this www

[Click for example](https://overpass.kumi.systems/api/interpreter?data=%5Btimeout:15%5D%5Bout:json%5D;is_in(44.1894724,7.1499639)-%3E.a;relation(pivot.a)[%22boundary%22=%22protected_area%22];out%20tags%20bb;)

all utf8 characters are not correctly codified.
This is my access routine:

```
var
  Web     : TIdHTTP;
  Sito    : String;
  hIOHand : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

begin
  Url := TIdURI.URLEncode(Url);


  try
    Web := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    hIOHand := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    hIOHand.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    hIOHand.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2,sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvSSLv23];
    Web.IOHandler := hIOHand;
    Web.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';


    Web.Request.UserAgent := INET_USERAGENT;       //Custom user agent string
    Web.RedirectMaximum := INET_REDIRECT_MAX;      //Maximum redirects
    Web.HandleRedirects := INET_REDIRECT_MAX <> 0; //Handle redirects
    Web.ReadTimeOut := INET_TIMEOUT_SECS * 1000;   //Read timeout msec
    try
      Sito := Web.Get(Url);
      Web.Disconnect;
    except
      on e : exception do
        Sito := 'ERR: ' +Url+#32+e.Message;
    end;
  finally
    Web.Free;
    hIOHand.Free;
  end;
```

I try all solution but in the Sito var i find alltime wrong characthers, for example correct value of the "name" is

"name": "Aire d'adhésion du Parc national du Mercantour",

but after the Get instruction i have

"name": "Aire d'adhÃ©sion du Parc national du Mercantour",

Do you have idea where is my error?
Thankyou all!

Comment: delphi XE6 the var are: Web     : TIdHTTP;
  Sito    : String;

Comment: FWIW, the link in your question doesn't work here.

Comment: i changed the link in the text, and added the var section. tx

Comment: You should not be setting the `DefStringEncoding` for HTTP. You should not be enabling `sslvSSLv2`, `sslvSSLv3`, or `sslvSSLv23` for SSL. You should not be setting the  `Request.CharSet`. And you do not need to call `Disconnect`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi 2009+, which includes XE6, `string` is a UTF-16 encoded `UnicodeString`.

You are using the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `string`. It decodes the sent text to UTF-16 using whatever charset is reported by the response.  If the text is not decoding properly, it likely means the response is not reporting a correct charset. If the wrong charset is used, the text will not decode properly.

The URL in question is, in fact, sending a response `Content-Type` header that is set to `application/json` without specifying a `charset` at all.  The default charset for `application/json` is UTF-8, but Indy does not know that, so it ends up using its own internal default instead, which is not UTF-8. That is why the text is not decoding properly when non-ASCII characters are present.

In which case, if you KNOW the charset will always be UTF-8, you have a few workarounds to choose from:

- you can set Indy's default charset to UTF-8 by setting the global `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit:

  ```
  GIdDefaultTextEncoding := encUTF8;
  ```
- you can use the `TIdHTTP.OnHeadersAvailable` event to change the `TIdHTTP.Response.Charset` property to `'utf-8'` if it is blank or incorrect.

  ```
  Web.OnHeadersAvailable := CheckResponseCharset;

  ...

  procedure TMyClass.CheckResponseCharset(Sender: TObject; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList; var VContinue: Boolean);
  var
    Response: TIdHTTPResponse;
  begin
    Response := TIdHTTP(Sender).Response;
    if IsHeaderMediaType(Response.ContentType, 'application/json') and (Response.Charset = '') then
      Response.Charset := 'utf-8';
    VContinue := True;
  end;
  ```
- you can use the other overloaded  version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that fills an output `TStream` instead of returning a `string`. Using a `TMemoryStream` or `TStringStream`, you can decode the raw bytes yourself using UTF-8:

  ```
  MStrm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Web.Get(Url, MStrm);
    MStrm.Position := 0;
    Sito := ReadStringFromStream(MStrm, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  finally
    SStrm.Free;
  end;
  ```

  ```
  SStrm := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    Web.Get(Url, SStrm);
    Sito := SStrm.DataString;
  finally
    SStrm.Free;
  end;
  ```

Comment: Perfect Remy, you are BIG! I use the last solution: using the TStringStream i changed the GET instructions as: Web.Get(Url,TStr); Sito := UTF8Decode(TStr.DataString) - TStr is my TStringStream -  and all is perfect! all characters are perfecty decode! Thankyou very much!!

Comment: @ondertol the **correct** way to use `TStringStream` in this situation is to use `TEncoding.UTF8` in its constructor, not using `UTF8Decode()` at all. I updated my answer with examples.

Comment: Remy… thankyou for your essential assistance, i reviewed the program as your code, i had only problem with the instruction TStr := TStringStream.Create(TEncoding.UTF8); (the compiler give a message "There is no overloaded version of 'Create' that can be called with these arguments" for solve it i insert a string for first parameter as TStr := TStringStream.Create(Stg,TEncoding.UTF8);... then all is perfect. Another thankyou !!!