# Indy server replaces specific characters

Tags: delphi, utf-8, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

I was trying to make my own webserver using Indy, for some sort of webpage. In my native language I frequently use the 'Ő' and 'Ű' characters, which would be fine, but for some reason, after the html file has been sent to the browser by the server, these characters get replaced with 'O' and 'U'. It's annoying me for like a week now, and I can't figure out, why does this keep happening. What do I need to set on the server, so it sends the page correctly? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to encode your webpage by UTF8 and declare that this webpage contains UTF8.

Comment: How can I declare that a webpage contains UTF8? What meta do I need to use?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800270/delphi-indy-utf8

Comment: I already tried some of the solutions, that are mentioned there, and they did not help. Also, I'm working on a server, and not on a client.

Comment: If you would show the code excerpt of your server, I could shortly show you how to add UT8 encoding.

Comment: I implement this event: `procedure TMainForm.WebserverCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: IdHTTPResponseInfo);`, then I decide that what kind of html event is happening (post or get): `if (ARequestInfo.Command = 'POST') then {... doesn't matter ...} else ` I use my system to decide wich html file do I need to send, than I do this: `AResponseInfo.ContentText := TFile.ReadAllText(Pages[I].FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);`, to send the page back. When I use a breakpoint, the specified characters are still in the variable.

Comment: You're supposed to put the code in your question. It's harder to read the code in comments. That's what you should do right from the start. You're discouraging community members to answer your question when they see no code in the question that *is* about the code.

Comment: Sorry, I do it better next time!

Comment: @KissKonrád You are reading the file data into a `String` for the `ContentText`, converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16. But you are not telling Indy to convert the `ContentText` back to UTF-8 when transmitting to the web browser, or telling the web browser that the text is UTF-8. Since you are serving a file from disk, consider using `ContentStream` instead of `ContentText`, eg: `AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html; charset=utf-8'; AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TIdReadFileExclusiveStream.Create(Pages[I].FileName);`

Comment: @KissKonrád Alternatively, `AResponseInfo` has `(Smart)ServeFile()` methods, eg: `AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html; charset=utf-8'; AResponseInfo.ServeFile(AContext, Pages[I].FileName);` or `AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html; charset=utf-8'; AResponseInfo.SmartServeFile(AContext, ARequestInfo, Pages[I].FileName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the responding charset like that:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Hallo Web ŐŰ';
end;
```

Comment: I wrote the charset like this: `UTF-8`, and not lowercase. Thank you very much!

Comment: That should not make a difference. I tested it with Chrome and it is case insensitive.

Comment: Probably not a great idea to load the content into memory, and convert to string. Better to use a stream in the way that Remy describes in comments